# Как реализовать шаблон

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, php

Есть интерфейс, который будет общим для всех объектов:

```
interface Config_Interfacefunction
{

    public function read($file){
        echo 'read'.$file;
        }
}
```

Нужно создавать несколько типов объектов , каждый тип поведение которых описываем в классах:

```
 class Config_Config
{
    public function Con(){
        echo 'conf';
        }
}

 class Config_Config2
{
    public function Con(){
        echo 'conf2';
        }
    public function Joi(){
        echo 'Joi';
        }   
}
```

Теперь хочу общий класс, который будет создавать объекты разного типа в зависимости от переданного аргумента.

```
class Con {
    public $root=19;
     public function __construct($instance) {
       .....
    }

    }

$obj=new Con(new ......);//что здесь писать???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На википедии есть прекрасная [статья](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) с примерами, в том числе для PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Шаблон "Strategy" здесь не совсем уместен. Стратегия хорошо подходит в тех случаях, когда требуется именно выбор определенной стратегии( кэп ). Например, у вас есть базовый абстрактный класс с методом `Say()`, от него наследуется три класса с различной реализацией метода `Say()`, и, наконец, у вас есть класс выборки стратегии, в конструктор которого передается объект нашего базового абстрактного класса, в этом классе так же есть делегирующий метод Say(). Это и есть типичная стратегия.

---

В вашем же случае наиболее подходящим будет [паттерн Factory Method](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) . Он как раз призван для создания объектов класса в зависимости от ситуации.